# How to show data in relate table laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 table called category_order , order , order_detail . now i want to showing total_order in another table but its related table ,you can see this table like this :

category_order:

```
category_order
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |  cat_name  | balance    |    some_data
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |   phone    | 10000000   |    
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |     PC     | 50000000   |   
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 | Electronic | 500000000  |    
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

order:

```
order
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |  cat_id    |some_data   |    some_data
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |   1        | some_data  |    
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |   1        | some_data  |   
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |   2        | some_data  |    
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

order_detail

```
order_detail
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |  order_id  | price      |   qty   
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |   1        |   1000     |    10   // so from this i can create total 10000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |   1        |   2000     |    5    // and this 10000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |   2        |   5000     |    10   // and this 50000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

this 3 table is related ,and now i want to show data like this :

```
category_order
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |  cat_name  |  balance   |   total_order
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |   phone    | 10000000   |    20000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |     PC     | 50000000   |    50000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 | Electronic | 50000000   |    . . .  .
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

and its my relation

```
 Models Order
    public function category_order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\CategoryOrder::class ,'cat_id');
    }

 Models Order_detail
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Order::class ,'order_id');
    }
```

so what i can do for this ???

and my step now is just selecting on category_order like this :

```
 public function get_belanja()
    {
        $belanja = CategoryOrder::where('status', 'active')->get();
        return response()->json($belanja ,200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the necessary tables (and subqueries to do the totals calculation) to `CategoryOrder` query. One approach using Laravel's query builder is:

First calculate the totals for individual orders by joining the order_details table (using `OrderDetail` model or `DB::table('order_details')`.

```
$orderTotals = OrderDetail::select(
    DB::raw('sum(qty*price) as order_total'),
    'order_id',
    'cat_id'
)->join('orders', 'order_id', 'orders.id')
->groupBy('order_id');
```

Then user the join the above query using `joinSub` to `CategoryOrder` select statement you have.

```
$categoryTotals = CategoryOrder::select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(order_total) as cat_total'))
    ->joinSub($orderTotals, 'order_totals', function($join){ //this is where we are joining the above query as a sub query (first param) and we name it 'order_totals' in the second param for future reference
        $join->on('id', '=', 'order_totals.category_id');
    })
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->where('status', 'active')
    ->get();
```